# How to find all model names in a yii application?

Tags: yii

I am using a Module in yii, and the module will be used when a property of an application model is true.

How can I get all the model names available in my application so that i can establish relations on conditional basis between application models having the property and the module?

Answer (score -1):

You can use below method to get class name:

```
public function modelName()
{
    return __CLASS__;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$model = new State();
echo $model->getModelName();
```

Comment: I need the list of all model names in the application environment, not the name of the current model object.

Comment: Your answer gives the name of the current class and not what the question is about. I want the list of all the Models which are in the Yii app environment. I already have gone through the link before posting the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438660/yii-how-to-retrieve-model-data-into-a-layout-page

Comment: Actually the answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247862/get-all-model-in-yii