# Get all of model names in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-modules

I am creating a module for our web application. I am using Yii 1.1.14. How do I retrieve all of the model names?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438660/yii-how-to-retrieve-model-data-into-a-layout-page) but still I got no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if my understanding of your question is correct. If you have to retrieve the name of all your models, then maybe your approach to the problem at hand is not optimal? Anyway here is what i would approach the problem:

```
foreach(glob('./protected/modules/<module-name>/models/*.php') as $filename){
    echo str_replace(".php", "", $filename)."<br/>";
}
```

This iterates through all files in your models sub-folder within your module and displays them after removing the ".php" part. If you want to access all models for the entire project change

```
glob('./protected/modules/<module-name>/models/*.php')
```

to

```
glob('./protected/models/*.php')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what I need. I'll just remove the file path. I thought there is an internal function to call for retrieving model names.

Comment: @ltlynx Since Yii autoloads all models as and when needed, it doesn't maintain a list of all the models that are available. So I don't think there is an internal function to call for retrieving model names...

Comment: I think I just found out a solution that could make it list all the models on any modules. I just added this code to our gii generator inside our controller class if (!array_key_exists(Yii::app()->params['model_names'])) { Yii::app()->params['model_names'] = array(); } if (in_array('<?php echo "$this->modelClass" ?>', Yii::app()->params['model_names'])) { Yii::app()->params['model_names'][] = "'$this->modelClass'"; }