# How to use models from models/ in layouts/main.php in yii 2.0 (basic template)

Tags: yii, frameworks

I have started to learn about Yii framework about day ago and I came up with the problem.

I have downloaded basic application template (so that you know the structure of my application).

I would like to use one of my classes's function from "models/" in the "views/layouts/main.php", however, I am not sure how I can access them from "main.php". I have searched around the internet and none of the solutions have helped me.

1. I've read about widget creation, so I can use it in "main.php" in this link - [Yii - how to retrieve model data into a layout page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438660/yii-how-to-retrieve-model-data-into-a-layout-page#answer-8443734), but this does not provide my version of Yii as I coulnt not find protected folder and etc. So I was kind of confused.
2. Also read some other solution, but they did not help me as well.

What would you suggest me to do? Because I am currently have no clue about the solution. I am a newbiew in this framework, so, don't judge me hard :)

**UPDATED: [SOLUTION]**

```
// use statement on top of main.php like the other use statements
use app\models\Modelname; 

// anywhere in the file
.... 
$myModel = new Modelname; 
$myModel->myFunction();
... 

// Or if it is a static function: 
Modelname::myFunction();
```

This is how to access model files (classes) from folder **models/** from for example **views/layouts/main.php**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the deal - view is actually only a "view". View should only represent some data, but not do something with this data. You don't want to have any logic in the view.

Anyway, if you want to show something from your model - you should pass this model through controller, which renders your view.

Controller will look like:

```
$model = new Device;
$this->render('index', array(
    'model' => $model
));
```

Then you can use it in the view, normally to get some data from the model.

You could also get it directly in the view, but this is not good practice.

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html) can you read some basics about models and best practices how to use them.

**Update [Yii 1.x]**
To use Model-Class specifically in your main.php, import it at the place you want to use it:

```
     Yii::import('application.models.LoginForm');
```

After that you can normally use functions from your Model Class.

**Update 2**
Namespaces in Yii2:

```
use yii\models\LoginForm;
```

at the start of your main.php layout-File. Look also at the "Layouts" part [here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#accessing-data-in-views)

Comment: This is not what I am asking about. I know about this and view files. 
I am asking specifically about __views/layouts/main.php__ and how to get function from classes from __models/__ folder. For example, I would like to check whether user have logged in or not with my own function. How would I call the public function from the class __LoginForm__  (__class LoginForm extends Model__).  __LoginForm::isUserLoggedIn()__ - this does not work , what sould other suggestions be?

Comment: Bfcm, that means that after I import it, I can use the function like this LoginForm::isUserLoggedIn()? Is is the best practive or there is better way of doing it? Because I don't want to learn bad way :)

Comment: There is another possibility to use namespaces. Read about "namespaces in Yii2". 
It could also happen, that Yii::import() doesn't work in Yii2, because I use Yii1, but it should.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Pleasure to help you :)